# Julia and Slurm setup

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, slurm

I have a master node and 3 compute nodes.
Julia on master node is on /apps and on /state/p1/apps.

I do not have julia as a slurm module.

How should I setup Julia installation so that I can invoke a Julia script through slurm using ClusterManager?

Currently I get an error

```
srun: error: node-0-2: tasks 0-2: Exited with exit code 2
```

Julia script:

```
using ClusterManagers

addprocs(SlurmManager(3), partition="slurm", t="00:5:00")

hosts = []
pids = []
for i in workers()
        host, pid = fetch(@spawnat i (gethostname(), getpid()))
        println(host)
        push!(hosts, host)
        push!(pids, pid)
end


# The Slurm resource allocation is released when all the workers have
# exited
for i in workers()
        rmprocs(i)
end
```

**UPDATE**

I seem to have a slurm issue. Tried updating ClusterManagers as suggested by @user338207 and SlurmManager(3) instead of SlurmManager(2) as suggested by crstnbr.

```
srun -N 2 julia parallel2.jl
srun: error: node-0-2: task 2: Exited with exit code 1
srun: error: node-0-2: task 2: Exited with exit code 1
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds
node-0-1 3 out of 3
node-0-1
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds
ERROR: LoadError: connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
try_yieldto(::Base.##296#297{Task}, ::Task) at ./event.jl:189
wait() at ./event.jl:234
wait(::Condition) at ./event.jl:27
stream_wait(::TCPSocket, ::Condition, ::Vararg{Condition,N} where N) at ./stream.jl:42
wait_connected(::TCPSocket) at ./stream.jl:258
```

but srun -N 2 hostname works fine

Comment: It would be good to know what your current approach is.

Comment: To answer your question, you don't have to setup Julia in a special way. Since Julia is still changing (and cluster admins probably do not keep up with updates) I suggest you simply use binaries from julialang.org

Comment: If installation is correct, what is causing the srun error?

Answer (score 1):

**This how you could setup julia on a linux cluster and run a parallel task via slurm.**

1. Download generic linux binaries from [julialang.org](https://julialang.org/downloads/)
2. Put them somewhere, for example into `~/bin/julia-v0.6` (you will have to create this folder).
3. Create a `julia-environment` file in the same folder with content

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/bin/julia-v0.6/bin:$PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/julia-v0.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export CPATH=$HOME/bin/julia-v0.6/include:$CPATH
   ```
4. Now you can use `sbatch myjobfile.sh` to submit a job file like

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -l
   #SBATCH --nodes=2
   #SBATCH --ntasks=4
   #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
   #SBATCH --time=00:10:00
   #SBATCH --output=myoutput.log
   #SBATCH --job-name=my-julia-job

   source $HOME/julia-v0.6/julia-environment
   cd working/folder/of/your/choice
   julia my_clustermanager_script.jl
   ```

(Note that one could also put a `srun --ntasks=1` in front of the julia command, see this [github issue](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/ClusterManagers.jl/issues/84).)

Of course, you can also start an interactive job by allocating resources with `salloc`.

**UPDATE:**

Running the job script above (via `sbatch myjobfile.sh`) with `my_clustermanager_script.jl` being (note `SlurmManager(4)` instead of `SlurmManager(3)`)

```
using ClusterManagers

addprocs(SlurmManager(4), t="00:5:00")

hosts = []
pids = []
for i in workers()
        host, pid = fetch(@spawnat i (gethostname(), getpid()))
        println(host)
        push!(hosts, host)
        push!(pids, pid)
end


# The Slurm resource allocation is released when all the workers have
# exited
for i in workers()
        rmprocs(i)
end
```

I get the following output files:

`myoutput.log`:

```
connecting to worker 1 out of 4
connecting to worker 2 out of 4
connecting to worker 3 out of 4
connecting to worker 4 out of 4
cheops30410
cheops30410
cheops30414
cheops30414
```

`job0000.out`: `julia_worker:9009#173.12.2.191`

`job0001.out`: `julia_worker:9010#173.12.2.191`

`job0002.out`: `julia_worker:9010#173.12.2.192`

`job0003.out`: `julia_worker:9009#173.12.2.192`

Comment: sudo sacct says "FAILED" and no error or output file is created

Comment: srun: unrecognized option '--enable-threaded-blas=false'
Try "srun --help" for more information
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds

Comment: julia paralle2.jl returns srun: unrecognized option '--enable-threaded-blas=false'
Try "srun --help" for more information
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds
WARNING: dropping worker: file not created in 63 seconds

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I'd (wildly) guess that ClusterManagers.jl adds an option `--enable-threaded-blas=false` implicitly which your slurm can't handle?

Comment: looks like I have to try out MPI.jl

Comment: @crstnbr Should slurm automatically copy the julia file to the various worker nodes to execute? In my output file, I get "ERROR: could not open file /my/working/directory/my_clustermanager_script.jl". I'm launching sbatch from the login node.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar script as crstnbr, and in fact, I have also run into the issue `srun: unrecognized option '--enable-threaded-blas=false'`. I had to change `src/slurm.jl` has decribed here:

https://github.com/JuliaParallel/ClusterManagers.jl/issues/75#issuecomment-319919108

This change has been implemented in version 0.2.0 of ClusterManagers.jl, maybe you are still using version 0.1.2. If this is the case, then an upgrade might solve the issue.

Julia does not let you upgrade a package with local modification. Such packages will have a + sign following the version number.

Here are the steps to upgrade a dirty package if you are not interested in keeping the local modifications (in particular if the new version already includes the changes that you made to your local copy):

```
cd ~/.julia/v0.6/ClusterManagers/
git diff # show your modification
cp -R ~/.julia/v0.6/ClusterManagers/ ~/ClusterManagers.bak # backup copy
git checkout . # discard your modification
julia --eval 'Pkg.update("ClusterManagers")' # upgrade the package
```

Comment: Pkg.Status() shows version as 0.1.2+. How can I confirm if it is 0.2.0?

Comment: I expanded my response to show how you can upgrade to version 0.2.0. Does it work?